# SQL Syntax error a or near

Tags: sql, postgresql, jakarta-ee

I have a sql problem.
 
My problem is that one of my statement doesn't work for an unknowned reason. It seems stupid but I can't understand why.

```
statement.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO calamar.calamar.derogationlinuxexecution (id, chemin, user, serveur, justificatif) " 
+ " VALUES ('"+id+"', '"+chemin+"', '"+user+"', '"+serveur+"', '"+justificatif+"');");
```

I got that error: `org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near « user »`

I've tryed to `System.out.println` my request and I got:

```
INSERT INTO calamar.calamar.derogationlinuxexecution (id, chemin, user, serveur, justificatif)  VALUES ('35', '/etc/pssw', 'm421339', 'qviP153', 'jusitifcation de ouf');
```

I really don't understand where am I wrong. When I delete the "user," and "m421339," it work with no problem.

Comment: You're properly escaping `id`, `chemin`, ..., right? Or better, why don't you use placeholders?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`user` is a [reserved word for postgresql](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-keywords-appendix.html), so the parser is getting confused by the column name.

You can either re-name the column to something non-reserved ("username" is popular for this), or you can wrap the column name in double quotes:

```
INSERT INTO calamar.calamar.derogationlinuxexecution
  (id, chemin, "user", serveur, justificatif)
  VALUES
  ('35', '/etc/pssw', 'm421339', 'qviP153', 'jusitifcation de ouf');
```

Comment: If you are using linux then replace command might be helpful.